# Google Tag Manager 4 container not getting refreshed for android

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I have this code to refresh and download a new container but it never does. i've waited over 12 hours to get a refreshed container and the ONLY way I've found it to work, is if I go through the GTM Console and manually download the container file and then put that with my project.
I thought that the following code snippet would do this automatically for me.

```
mTagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context);

        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = mTagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(BuildConfig.ANALYTIC_CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.default_container);
        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                AnalyticsManager.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                containerHolder.refresh();
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

anyone have any idea what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mTagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context);

```
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = mTagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(BuildConfig.ANALYTIC_CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.default_container);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            AnalyticsManager.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            //neeeded to have this : 
            getContainerHolder().getContainer();
            containerHolder.refresh();
        }
    }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: What is the difference between release and refresh?

Comment: No idea, I just saw the google docs saying to refresh the container which makes sense.   releasing a container would mean perhaps setting it to null, but not sure.